# Comparing JSON array objects to Ruby String

Tags: ruby, arrays, json

I have a JSON array structured like this:

```
{"data":[{"Chris":[{"long":10,"lat":19}]},{"Scott":[{"long":9,"lat":18}]}]}
```

I am then reading from the array in ruby, and I have started to iterate through the JSON array like so:

```
objArray = JSON.parse(File.open('public/test.json').read);
sections = objArray["data"]

sections.each do |subsections|
        subsections.each do |supersub|
            supersub.each do |obj| 

                #Check if variable Usrname is equal to a name in the JSON array
            end
        end 
    end
```

As the comment in the loop says, I need to compare the variable Usrname to the names in the JSON array i.e "Chris" and "Scott" to see if Usrname matches any of them. How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
username = 'Chris'
sections.each do |user_coords|
  user_coords.each do |user, coords|
    if user == username
      # Do stuff here...
      puts "OK: #{coords}"
    end
  end
end

# OK: [{"long"=>10, "lat"=>19}]
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Do you know how I can then edit the coords of the name?

Comment: You can access them via `user_coords[name]` - that is the array of hashes of "lat/long" per user.

Comment: SO do I do it like this: `rb_hash[user_coords[Usrname]] << {lng: Lng.to_i, lat: Lat.to_i}`